# Find the second highest salary

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n, hierarchical-query

Well it is a well known question. Consider the below

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName    Department      Salary   
----------- --------------- --------------- ---------
1           T Cook          Finance         40000.00
2           D Michael       Finance         25000.00
3           A Smith         Finance         25000.00
4           D Adams         Finance         15000.00
5           M Williams      IT              80000.00
6           D Jones         IT              40000.00
7           J Miller        IT              50000.00
8           L Lewis         IT              50000.00
9           A Anderson      Back-Office     25000.00
10          S Martin        Back-Office     15000.00
11          J Garcia        Back-Office     15000.00
12          T Clerk         Back-Office     10000.00
```

We need to find out the second highest salary

```
With Cte As
(
  Select 
    level
    ,Department
    ,Max(Salary) 
 From plc2_employees
 Where level = 2
 Connect By Prior (Salary) > Salary)
Group By level,Department
)

Select 
    Employeeid
    ,EmployeeName
    ,Department
    ,Salary
From plc2_employees e1
Inner Join Cte e2 On e1.Department = e2.Department
Order By 
    e1.Department
    , e1.Salary desc
    ,e1.EmployeeID
```

is somehow not working... I am not getting the correct result. Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: You're not interested in Larry Ellison, but in someone else at Oracle? (Sorry, this is what the subject sounded like to me...)

Comment: Yes the question is similar to that and other SO question.. I have already seen..but I am trying to solve it using the Connect by approach.. Reason I am new to it and trying to implement that in this context...

Comment: You can't solve this using a recursive query (okay, you might be able to, but it's not the right tool for the job). The specific problem you're running is that the clause `Connect By Prior (Salary) > Salary` is causing each salary to be joined to every salary below it.

Comment: Allan , I am trying to enhance the first method proposed here ( http://techforum4u.com/entry.php/311-How-To-Query-Nth-Largest-Value-From-A-Table).. please help

Comment: @user1025901: The method suggested in that link is poorly thought out. Let's say you have 1000 employees: using this method you would create an interim result set of 499,500 (the inequality join will create `n*(n-1)/2` records, if none are equal) records in order to find the one record you're looking for. This is incredibly inefficient, particularly when there's a known solution that uses a feature better suited to the task (analytic queries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to teach yourself how to deal with CONNECT BY, you should first find a problem that is suited to the construct. CONNECT BY is meant for processing data that's in a hierarchical form, which your example is not. Salaries are not related to each other in a hierarchical fashion. Trying to force-fit a construct on the wrong problem is frustrating and doesn't really teach you anything.

Take a look at the classic employee-manager relationship in the demo HR schema you can install with Oracle. All employees report to a manager, including managers (except the top guy). You can then use this schema to create a query to show, for example, the Organization Chart for the company.

Answer (score 7):

Something like

```
select * from
(
select EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Department, Salary, 
rank () over (partition by Department order by Salary desc) r
from PLC2_Employees
)
where r = 2
```

Edit - tested it and it gives the answer you expected.

Comment: Well I know this approaches ...even it can also be done using Dense_Rank also...+ co-related subquery etc.. I am trying a different approach for solving it using the connect by as i am new to it...

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from your original question. Not sure connect by is a good approach for this.

Comment: Hi Greg, I am basically trying to enhance the first solution propose here(http://techforum4u.com/entry.php/311-How-To-Query-Nth-Largest-Value-From-A-Table)

Answer (score 4):

`START WITH … CONNECT BY` is designed to explore data that forms a graph, by exploring all possible descending paths. You specify the root nodes in the `START WITH` clause **and the node connections in the `CONNECT BY` clause (not in the `WHERE` clause)**.

The `WHERE` clause filters will be processed **after** the hierachical conditions, same for `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` (of course because `GROUP BY` is computed after `WHERE`).

Therefore you MUST here `CONNECT BY PRIOR department = department` for example. You must also avoid that a node connection is done between two salaries when there is an intermediate salary.

Therefore the final query would resemble this:

```
SELECT level
     , Department
     , Salary
  FROM plc2_employees pe1
 START WITH pe1.salary = (select max(salary) from plc2_employees pe2 WHERE pe2.Department = pe1.Department)
 CONNECT BY PRIOR pe1.Department = pe1.Department
        AND PRIOR pe1.Salary > pe1.Salary
        AND PRIOR pe1.Salary = ( SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM plc2_employees pe3
                                  WHERE pe3.Department = pe1.Department
                                    AND pe3.Salary > pe1.Salary
                               )
```

The recursion condition states that there is no intermediate salary between the child row and the parent row.

Note that this will really be unefficient…

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it gives second highest salary

```
select MAX(Salary) as Salary 
from Employee_salary 
where Salary not in (select MAX(Salary) from Employee_salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
select * from 
employee e1 
where 2 = (select count (distinct (salary)) 
from employee e2 
where e2.salary >=e1.salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
It gives second highest salary...

```
select MAX(Salary) as Salary 
from Employee_salary 
where Salary not in (select MAX(Salary) from Employee_salary )
```

If you want to find nth highest salary than you can use following query....
you need to do just one change.....
Put the value of N=nth highest

Cheers....:)

```
SELECT * FROM Employee_salary Emp1 
WHERE (N-1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary)) 
               FROM Employee_salary Emp2 
               WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

Comment: Try this, Its tested :)

Answer (score 0):

**find out second highest salary from employee table having column as salary:**
**Database : DB2**

```
with t as
(
select distinct salary from employee order by salary desc
),
tr as 
(
select salary, row_Number() over() r from t 
)
select salary from tr where r = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work -

```
SELECT MIN(Salary) 
FROM employee 
WHERE salary IN (SELECT TOP 2 salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC)
```

Answer (score -3):

First, select the distinct salaries in descending order (from greatest to least), from that set select the top 2 and put in ascending order (placing number 2 on top), then from those 2 select top 1:

```
select top 1 s.Salary
  from 
   (select top 2 t.Salary
      from
          (select distinct Salary
             from PLC2_Employees
            order by Salary desc) t
     order by Salary asc) s
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `TOP`.

Comment: Yes that is true(top is not supported in Orcle we can use Row_Number() or RowNum for that) .. and also this query will not handle ties(if run in sql server or other rdbms that supports TOP) hopefully